# BlackBerry wiping the side-effects of Outlook 2007 rules?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, blackberry, rules

I've just upgraded from Outlook 2003 to Outlook 2007 and I have a number of (client-side) rules that categorize and flag emails based on who they've come from (particular senders, or whether I'm in the to/cc fields, the only recipient, etc.). These work just fine and while not exactly as cleanly as in 2003, it'll do.

Today, for the first time since the upgrade, I've switched my BlackBerry on.

Now, when mail arrives, the rules are run properly, but a few seconds later when the mail is also downloaded onto the BlackBerry, the category and flag are wiped.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Having opened a bounty, I actually did some deeper searching and think I've found the answer.

Basically it was the Cached Exchange Mode being enabled (I run Xobni which recommends that).

The issue is that the BES and the client-side rules are both changing the message and because of the Cached Exchange Mode this was resulting in two copies, one of which (the first, client-side amended) is stored in a Sync - Conflicts folder (which is visible if you search for it, clicking on the search for related versions).

I could have disabled all the client-only rules, but then I wouldn't have the flag and categories, but disabling Cached Exchange Mode does the trick. (Of course, it might break Xobni).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/KB19222

Cached Exchange Mode isn't really a good thing. The whole point of Exchange and BES is that you're working with dynamic, real-time, push email. But, it has some virtues obviously.

The article I've linked to discusses your issue, including a potential solution.

Comment: The issue I have to answer now is whether Xobni is impacted - then it's a trade-off, flags and cats vs proper search ...